# HttpClient To Get List With Async/Await Operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, httpclient

I'm trying to get a list from a web api which I've written before. Then I'll use that list in Xamarin.Forms ListView. My code is here:

```
public static class DataSource
{

    public static async Task<Restoran[]> GetRestoransAsync()
    {
        // ... Use HttpClient.
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // ... Read the string.
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var restorans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Restoran[]>(result);
            return restorans;
        }

    }

}
```

My ContentPage:

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView;
    List<Restoran> restorans = new List<Restoran>();
    async Task LoadRestorans()
    {
        restorans = (await DataSource.GetRestoransAsync()).ToList();
    }

    public MenuPage(string masa)
    {
        var loadData = LoadRestorans();
        loadData.Wait();
        listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement)
        {
        ItemsSource = restorans,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var nativeCell = new CustomCell();
                return nativeCell;
            })
        };
    }
}
```

But when I debugged this code, "LoadRestorans()" method has called just before initialization of "restorans" list. I think I don't understand the mentality of async methods. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

Create the page using an async factory method

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage {
    ListView listView;
    List<Restoran> restorans = new List<Restoran>();

    private async Task LoadRestoransAsync() {
        restorans = (await DataSource.GetRestoransAsync()).ToList();
        listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement) {
            ItemsSource = restorans,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var nativeCell = new CustomCell();
                return nativeCell;
            })
        };
    }

    public MenuPage(string masa) {
        //...        
    }

    public static async Task<MenuPage> CreateMenuPageAsync(string masa) {
        var page = new MenuPage(masa);
        await page.LoadRestoransAsync();
        return pagel
    }
}
```

Then use it like this in other async event handlers

```
var page = await MenuPage.CreateMenuPageAsync("<masa here>");
```

**OR**

do it in the `OnAppearing` event.

Subscribe to the `Appearing` event of the page/view

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    this.Appearing += Page_Appearing;
}
```

and call your async code on an actual even handler

```
private async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //...call async code here

    //unsubscribing from the event
    this.Appearing -= Page_Appearing;
}
```

The full class would look something like this

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage {
    ListView listView;
    List<Restoran> restorans = new List<Restoran>();

    private async Task LoadRestoransAsync() {
        restorans = (await DataSource.GetRestoransAsync()).ToList();
        listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement) {
            ItemsSource = restorans,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var nativeCell = new CustomCell();
                return nativeCell;
            })
        };
    }

    public MenuPage(string masa) {
        //...        
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing() {
        this.Appearing += Page_Appearing;
    }

    private async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //...call async code here
        await LoadRestoransAsync();

        //unsubscribing from the event
        this.Appearing -= Page_Appearing;
    }

}
```

What was happening before was that by calling `.Wait()`, which is a blocking call the class was mixing async and blocking calls (like `.Result` and `.Wait()`) which can lead to deadlocks. Hence why you were unable to go past the method when you tried to test it.

Comment: I used your second solution. It worked but I had to update listview  and ContentPage's children to show items on screen. Maybe I can find a better solution but for now it's ok.I couldn't try your first solution because I don't have any async event handler to use that await line inside of it. Anyways, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It is call before `restorans` because the constructor `MenuPage` is called before the initialization of properties.

I would suggest

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView;
    List<Restoran> restorans;
    async Task<Restoran[]> LoadRestorans()
    {
        return await DataSource.GetRestoransAsync();
    }

    public MenuPage(string masa)
    {
        this.restorans = LoadRestorans().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToList();
        listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement)
        {
        ItemsSource = this.restorans,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                var nativeCell = new CustomCell();
                return nativeCell;
            })
        };
    }
}
```

Note: I have not compiled this code, but this should be proper code as per my understanding.

Comment: `ItemSource` also accepts array, so my advice use array.

Comment: Not working, it cannot pass the "this.restorans =..." line.

Comment: HTTP Client example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Test code is working, but it isn't working in my case. When I put that line into the `MenuPage` method, it cannot pass that line, as i said before. I don't know why.